# why does it fail to create an app engine under google cloud project?

Tags: google-app-engine

```
gcloud config set project lov
gcloud beta app create --region=us-central
```

it gives the error saying
'This application already exists and cannot be re-created'
But when I go the web page and try to click the 'app engine' menu, it shows
'This operation is not possible because no App Engine application was found for this project.'

Answer (score 1):

This might indicate that you're trying to reserve an application name which used to be assigned to GAE app some time ago. This app could have been  deleted already, even before Cloud Platform projects were introduced.

GAE application names cannot be re-used after deletion, so you would need to create a new project with a more unique name to use App Engine with it. Cloud Console suggests names like `genuinely-improbable-12345` in order to avoid possible similar name conflicts in the future.